# NSIS Script example to install extension on all browsers (Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, Safari)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon, nsis, safari-extension, browser-extension

i need to package my plugin into an installer so that it can install on all available browsers on the computer.

After browsing many topics, i found a couple of script to single install Chrome or FF script with NSIS that helped a lot, but i really need a full NSIS script that will be able to install the extension for all browsers in a single install.

I'm sure this has been built many times over and if anybody could share a script example i could tweak to my needs, it would be greatly appreciated as i could only find bits and pieces and would like to see how the big picture fits together.

My requirements are quite simple :

- got the files in XPi, CRX.. extension file format
- I need a windows installer (NSIS) to install the extension for each available scripts
- if it could feed from a server, that would be a plus, but not mendatory
- I use Kango framework, so using another solution is not an option for now

Thanks a lot for your help !
UPDATE : I'm still trying to figure it out and can't find much support, keep in mind i cannot use CROSSRider. Please help thanks a lot

Comment: If you need that and already found scripts for installing for single browsers, why not try and put it together? If you have specific problems with that you could ask about those.

Answer (score 3):

No need to reinvent the wheel there. I think you're looking for something like [crossrider.com](http://crossrider.com/), it's a cross-browser extension platform. Take a look specifically at the "Windows Installer" option on your app settings there - You can choose to bundle your extension with your installation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm currently using Kango Framework and loving it, for monetizing reasons i won't go with Crossrider and want to use a NSIS installation script or similar installer. Please help thanks a lot !

Comment: @user1548936 Crossrider is FREE so I am not sure what you mean re "monetization reasons"

Comment: Hi Soroush, take a look at what user1548936 asked again: "but i really need a full NSIS script that will be able to install the extension for all browsers in a single install.". As far as I know you can do that easily with the Crossrider platform (windows installer + bundle for all browsers), I don't know about Kango, maybe you can do that to but I had no experience with it. Hope it helps - check it out, you might like it.